# What site is appropriate for me to ask this question about identifying an antique?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I took a few photos of a grandfather clock inside a building, and I would like to know if anyone has seen it. I can't find the best site to ask my question. What do you recommend?

Comment: I was informed that I needed five XP on Area51, but I would be able to post a link to this question. Unfortunately, it said that the post could not be found, or that it wasn't linked to the current users. As far as I know, this URL does work, and I'm logged into the same account. So I don't know why it's giving me that error.

Comment: Which URL are you talking about? You gain your first 50 rep on Area 51 by confirming your email address.

Comment: I never received a link to confirm my e-mail in my inbox or spam folder. I do remember seeing a message about unlocking some sort of badge that would allow me to comment everywhere. Previously, I created this account using Facebook, so a while back I asked how I could add my e-mail address to this account so I can use my e-mail and password to log in.

Comment: Which post could not be found? This site is not Area 51, but Meta. (You asked your question in the right place, though.)

Comment: Okay, this is what I did. I clicked on ask question in Area51. It said I needed 5 reputation to ask a question, but I could paste the URL of my question. I assumed it wanted me to paste the meta stack exchange URL leading to this question, so that's what I did. It is https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306280/what-site-is-appropriate-for-me-to-ask-this-question-about-identifying-an-antiqu

Comment: I was able to go to my Area51 profile and saw the message to verify my e-mail, so that was fixed.

Comment: SIte recs seem on topic here

Comment: as an aside, and I feel a little bad for asking this - how does a blind person take photos? Even focus aside (and many people who can see .... do a horrible job) but actually going "there's a thing there, and I need a visual representation of it"?

Answer (score 2):

In the current form - I'm not sure its a "good" question. "Has anyone seen foo?" dosen't make a good question. *Identification* questions especially of the nature of "here's a photo of a thing- what is it?" don't work well - accessibility aside, they're not very searchable.

In *theory* the correct field to ask about such things is *horology* but alas, the SE site for that never made its way out of our new site creation process.

If its questions about a specific clock (and its somehow distinctive) and its history, and its old enough you might be able to shoehorn it into a history.se question. You might want to check there and its meta cause this feels slightly like a stretch

I'm of the opinion there's no really good fit for the question though as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'll try wedging it into one of the history sites. I am looking for anyone who may have seen this style of clocks, but I also want to know how it produces the chimes, which may be a scientific oor physical answer as well. I posted on Area51 about adding horology again. Also, what did you mean by, 'Has anyone seen foo' is not a good question? Of course I want to know if anyone knows what kind of clock this is.

Comment: ooh, that seems like pretty deep horology *but* if you can find out *about* it, its a start. Sadly history isn't one of the sites I'm active on so I have no idea how such wedging can be done.